# Awk substring a single character

Tags: linux, bash, awk, substring, gawk

Here is columns.txt

```
aaa bbb 3
ccc ddd 2
eee fff 1
3   3   g
3   hhh i
jjj 3   kkk
ll  3   mm
nn  oo  3
```

I can find the line where second column starts with "b":

```
awk '{if(substr($2,1,1)=="b") {print $0}}' columns.txt
```

I can find the line where second column starts with "bb":

```
awk '{if(substr($2,1,2)=="bb") {print $0}}' columns.txt
```

Why oh why can't I find the line where the second character in the second column is "b"?:

```
awk '{if(substr($2,2,2)=="b") {print $0}}' columns.txt
```

`awk -W version` == GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: because you're telling `substr()` to return 2 characters (the last arg) and then comparing the resulting 2-char string (e.g. `bb`) to the 1-char string `b` to see if they are identical, which of course they never can be.

Comment: I have been using this function as substr(field,start,end) where end is the Nth character of string. It had worked so far because I always searched from the first character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk 'substr($2,2,1) == "b"' columns.txt
aaa bbb 3
```

1. [`substr` function's 3rd argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is length of the string.
2. `print` is default action in awk.

Comment: Yes I meant 3rd argument only. Thanks @EdMorton.

Answer (score 3):

`awk '$2 ~ /^.b/' columns.txt` will also work.