# How can you compare entries between two columns in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to figure out whether the first letter of an amino acid is the same as its letter code.

For example, Glycine begins with G and its letter code is also (G)
On the other hand, Arginine begins with A but its letter code is (R)

I am trying to print out, as a result, the amino acids that have the same letter code and starting alphabet.

I have a CSV datafile in which the columns are delimited by ','

```
Name,One letter code,Three letter code,Hydropathy,Charge,Abundance,DNA codon(s)
Arginine,R,Arg,hydrophilic,+,0.0514,CGT-CGC-CGA-CGG-AGA-AGG
Asparagine,N,Asn,hydrophilic,N,0.0447,AAT-AAC
Aspartate,D,Asp,hydrophilic,-,0.0528,GAT-GAC
Glutamate,E,Glu,hydrophilic,-,0.0635,GAA-GAG
Glutamine,Q,Gln,hydrophilic,N,0.0399,CAA-CAG
Lysine,K,Lys,hydrophilic,+,0.0593,AAA-AAG
Serine,S,Ser,hydrophilic,N,0.0715,TCT-TCC-TCA-TCG-AGT-AGC
Threonine,T,Thr,hydrophilic,N,0.0569,ACT-ACC-ACA-ACG
```

I believe the code below is one way to compare columns, but I am wondering how I can extract the first letter from the first column and compare that with the alphabet in the second column

```
awk '{ if ($1 == $2) { print $1; } }' < foo.txt
```

Comment: [Using awk to print characters of specific index on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11401070/608639), [Awk substring a single character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25868784/608639), [Substring only the first column in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107090), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} substr($1,1,1) == $2' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Serine,S,Ser,hydrophilic,N,0.0715,TCT-TCC-TCA-TCG-AGT-AGC
Threonine,T,Thr,hydrophilic,N,0.0569,ACT-ACC-ACA-ACG
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                    ##Starting BEGIN section for awk here.
 FS=","                   ##Setting FS as comma here, field separator.
}                         ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN here.
substr($1,1,1) == $2      ##Using substr function of awk to get sub string from line, substr(line/variable/field, starting point, ending point) is method for using it. Getting 1st letter of $1 and comparing it with $2 of current line, if TRUE then it will print current line.
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: could you please explain how you managed to extract the first letter of first column? does substr($1,1,1) refers to the first letter of first column? How would you refer to the second letter of third column?

Comment: @VAnon, sure added complete explanation for code now, please do let me know in case of any queries here.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way using `grep`:

```
$ grep -E '^(.)[^,]*,\1' input.csv 
Serine,S,Ser,hydrophilic,N,0.0715,TCT-TCC-TCA-TCG-AGT-AGC
Threonine,T,Thr,hydrophilic,N,0.0569,ACT-ACC-ACA-ACG
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as RavinderSingh's expression, but field selector attribute is different.

```
awk -F "," 'substr($1,1,1) == $2' InFile

Serine,S,Ser,hydrophilic,N,0.0715,TCT-TCC-TCA-TCG-AGT-AGC
Threonine,T,Thr,hydrophilic,N,0.0569,ACT-ACC-ACA-ACG
```